# Are HTML form data and the formData object the same thing?

Tags: html, forms

What is the difference between HTML form data and the formData object (are they really the same thing when sent over to the server, except that formData object can be constructed programmatically?), and how does XMLHttpRequest objects have to do with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML form data is a broad term that can mean any of:

- the data entered into a form
- data collected from a form on the client
- data formatted in one of the enctypes that a form supports
- such data parsed into a more useful data structure in a programming language in software running on the server

The `FormData` object is an API for generating data in a compatible format.

`XMLHttpRequest` can accept an instance of `FormData` as the argument to its `send()` method, at which point it will get unpacked and a suitable `Content-Type` HTTP header for it will be included on the request.